# Hide comma between anchor tags in a div with CSS

Tags: css, hide

I have this kind of HTML:

```
<div class="meta">
    <a href="#">link</a>,
    <a href="#">link</a>,
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

How could I hide the commas with css?

I've tried:

```
.meta{
    display: none;
}
meta a{
    display: inline;
}
```

but this has no effect as it affects the parent. Also I tried:

```
.meta *:not(a){
    display: none;
}
```

...but this removes everything, so no luck!

Comment: Do you need the , in the html?

Comment: No, I just need to remove the "," (it's output by php but I have a slightly difficult access to it).

Answer (score 0):

I finally resorted to jquery with this:

```
jQuery('.meta').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).text(text.replace(',', ' ')); 
});
```

...but if anyone finds a CSS solution I will give them the answer.

Comment: no need JS, check the duplicate question for some ideas